# How to manipulate text of HTML li and append back in main li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

I am trying to replace underscores with some string in  list items but it's not changing in list item's original text. here is my code.

```
$.each($.parseHTML(customFormSentenceView), function (i, item) {
            if ($.parseHTML(customFormSentenceView)[i].outerText.indexOf('_') > -1) {
                var startindex = $.parseHTML(customFormSentenceView)[i].outerText.indexOf("_");
                var lastindex = $.parseHTML(customFormSentenceView)[i].outerText.lastIndexOf("_");
                var len = $.parseHTML(customFormSentenceView)[i].outerText.length;
                var initstring = $.parseHTML(customFormSentenceView)[i].outerText.substring(0, startindex);
                var endstring = $.parseHTML(customFormSentenceView)[i].outerText.substring(lastindex + 1, len);
                $.parseHTML(customFormSentenceView)[i].outerText = initstring +  endstring;

            }
        });
```

Comment: I believe `$.parseHTML` is creating a new object every time you call it. This means that you're setting the text for an element that is in memory, but not in the DOM, so nothing will change on the page. Try to find the actual items themselves on the page and manipulate them instead of creating copies (or create those copies but replace the original elements in the DOM entirely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i have to change in the object in loop because that's the part of original Object.

```
$.each(customFormSentenceView, function (i, item) {

            if ($(item).text().indexOf('_') > -1) {
                var startindex = $(item).text().indexOf("_");
                var lastindex = $(item).text().lastIndexOf("_");
                var len = $(item).text().length;
                var initstring = $(item).text().substring(0, startindex);
                var endstring = $(item).text().substring(lastindex + 1, len);
                refinedText += initstring  + endstring;
                $(item).text(refinedText);
            }
        });
```